# Cannot GET NodeJS error while running localhost

Tags: node.js, docker

hope everyone doing great.
I'm trying to convert this app to docker but I'm getting Cannot GET / NodeJS error
Here's my express.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const portNumber = 3000;
const sourceDir = "dist";
const expressStaticGzip = require("express-static-gzip");
app.use(
  "/",
  expressStaticGzip(sourceDir, {
    enableBrotli: true,
    orderPreference: ["br", "gz"],
    setHeaders: function(res, path) {
      res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=31536000");
    }
  })
);

app.listen(portNumber, "0.0.0.0", () => {
  console.log(`Express web server started: http://0.0.0.0:${portNumber}`);
  console.log(`Serving content from /${sourceDir}/`);
});
```

Here's my dockerfile

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .


CMD [ "node", "express.js" ]
```

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code and Dockerfile are correct, I think you forget to expose the docker port. ([docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose))

solution:

```
docker run -p <local-port>:<container-port> <image-name>
# docker run -p 3000:3000 image-name
```

Comment: (The `EXPOSE` is routine and almost every Dockerfile has it, but it's not actually necessary and does almost nothing.  The `docker run -p` option is required.)

Comment: Thanks mate, i've tried both options but still getting same error :(

Comment: after putting docker run -p 3000:3000 image-name, I'm getting Express web server started: http://0.0.0.0:3000
Serving content from /dist, and still localhost showing Cannot GET /

Comment: @Hassan I ran the code and it works for me, I think the problem is there is no directory 'dist' in your `Dockerfile`. If `dist` is in your local-host add option `-v ./dist:/usr/src/app/dist` too.

Comment: @SadeghHayeri how can I add dist?

Comment: There are three options I think.
1. Mount dist from your localhost using -v flag.
2. Copy dist directory/file from your localhost to your image using `ADD` or `COPY` commands in your Dockerfile. (like `COPY dist dist`)
3. Build your app and create a dist directory when creating your docker image.